# Why does my for loop on a scriptable object misses objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to loop over a scriptable object (the orderList) to determine if an item (included in the orderList) can be delivered (which means, if for a specific job, the craft time allocated is enough to have the item created). The problem is that I found out that the second item in the orderList was always missed while looping over and I can't identify why.

I checked the parameter of the second itemObject and the attributed job is correct, as well as the craft duration.
I added a debug log to check if the if condition rejected the item, but it seems that the function does just not loop over the second item, and goes directly from orderList.Container[0] to orderList.Container[2].

Does anybody have an idea on why the second item is ignored?

Here is the code for information:

```
foreach (var job in Job.GetValues(typeof(Job)))
        {
            Debug.Log("job: "+ job);
            int duration = 10;
            for (int i=0; i < orderList.Container.Count; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("item: " + orderList.Container[i].item.title);
                Debug.Log("pre-duration: " + duration);
                if ((orderList.Container[i].item.métier == job.ToString()) & (orderList.Container[i].hour <= duration))
                {
                    duration -= orderList.Container[i].hour;
                    Debug.Log("post-duration: " + duration);
                    inventory.AddItem(orderList.Container[i].item, orderList.Container[i].amount);
                    deliveryList.AddItem(orderList.Container[i].item, orderList.Container[i].amount);
                    orderList.RemoveItem(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give enough code (the precise types involved) but I'll take a side-bet that the problem has to do with logic like this...

```
i = 0: process orderList[0]...  remove orderList[0]  
// now the item that used to be orderList[1] is orderList[0]  
i = 1: process orderList[1] // the item that used to be orderList[2]  
// (skipping the original orderList[1])
```

Comment: Thanks! It fixed the issue. It seems so obvious now that you say it, but I guess I will need to be more careful now with deletion in list/objects.